# Why am I getting permission denied to my Firestore data?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have setup a simple Firestore database to store data and working on the rules/permissions. I am able to access data in one collection called "workplace" but I am unable to read the data in my new collection called "employee"

I have tried changing the rule to:

```
allow read: if true;
```

and I am able to read the data

my query in the app:

```
db.collection("employee")
                .whereEqualTo("workplaceId", w.getId())
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            Employee e = doc.toObject(Employee.class);
                            e.setId(doc.getId());
                            Log.d(TAG, "staff: " + e.getFirstName());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

my rules in firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /workplace/{workplaceID} {
      allow read: if resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    match /employee/{employeeID} {
        allow read: if resource.data.workplaceId == request.resource.data.workplaceId;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to get all documents in the "employee" collection where their "workplaceId" is equal to the data that I am passing in.

See below a link to an image of my db structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zzp4.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my issue here was that I was trying to use the rules to 'filter' the data, which is incorrect and will fail.

The query is already performing the filter here, so I simply just needed to change the rule to:

```
match /employee/{employeeID} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
```

This gave me access to the data and the query was only selecting the data that I wanted to retrieve.

Comment: You should still be checking that the user has permission to access the specific resource. Otherwise the query can be modified to include data that belongs to other users.